# How to automatically copy a cell range so then can modify the values without get #REF

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with these columns:

```
   A       B       C       D 
col1    col2    col3    col4
   1       2       3       4
   2       4       6       8
   1       3       5       7
```

And I want to copy all the rows from 4 which are not blank to other cells, for example:

```
   A       B       C       D      E       F      H       I      J     
col1    col2    col3    col4   col5    col6   col7    col8    col9 
   1       2       3       4              2       4       6       8
   2       4       6       8              1       3       5       7
   1       3       5       7
```

I don't want to use a formula, because then I want to modify a cell value (for example F3) without getting `#REF` error

If I use

```
F2: = A3:D
```

I get an error, an also I have the blank cells

Answer (score 0):

- select cells/range and then
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> - copies the values
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> - pastes values without formulas

Comment: Oh.. I forgot to add in my question that I want this to be an automated process!

Comment: I see, well it comes in my mind that you could bind a script to a button and copy over values just by clicking the button - this would, however, mean that range needs to be hardcoded into a script. let me know if you are interested in such a solution...